# Rust immutable borrow followed by mutating code in a same method

Tags: rust, immutability, mutable, borrow

here is a simplified version of a Font object I'm currently building for inclusion in an embedded system. Inside the Font, I implement a cache of already rasterized glyphs through a HashMap. The *retrieve()* method must first check if a specific glyph is already in the cache through the *find()* method. If not found, it must then build the glyph, put it in the cache and then return it to the caller.

The issue is that the *retrieve()* method must first do an immutable borrow before modifying the cache if the required glyph was not found. Can't find a way to get it to work properly. Here is the code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::RandomState;

type GlyphCharCode = u32;
type GlyphsCache = HashMap<GlyphCharCode, Glyph, RandomState>;

struct Glyph { a: u8 }

struct Font {
  cache: GlyphsCache
}

impl Font {
  fn new() -> Font {
    Font { cache: GlyphsCache::new() }
  }

  fn find(&self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> Option<&Glyph> {
    self.cache.get(&charcode)
  }

  fn retrieve(&mut self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> Option<&Glyph> {
    let result = self.find(charcode);
    match result {
      Some(glyph) => Some(glyph),
      None => { self.cache.insert(charcode, Glyph { a: 3u8 });
                self.find(charcode) }
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let charcode: GlyphCharCode = 3;
  let mut font = Font::new(); 
  if let Some(glyph) = font.retrieve(charcode) {
    println!("Glyph value: {}", glyph.a);
  }
}
```

and here are the error messages:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.cache` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:26:17
   |
22 |   fn retrieve(&mut self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> Option<&Glyph> {
   |               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
23 |     let result = self.find(charcode);
   |                  ------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
24 |     match result {
25 |       Some(glyph) => Some(glyph),
   |                      ----------- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
26 |       None => { self.cache.insert(charcode, Glyph { a: 3u8 });
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HashMap`'s [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API to implement your "borrow or else" pattern.

```
fn retrieve(&mut self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> &mut Glyph {
  self.cache.entry(charcode).or_insert(Glyph { a: 3u8 })
}
```

This does the exact same thing that you were trying to do: "Return if present, or fill it out and return otherwise", but it's built-in to `HashMap`.

You might consider using [`or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with), which takes a closure that is only called if the insertion actually needs to occur, if construction is expensive in your use case.

```
fn retrieve(&mut self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> &mut Glyph {
  self.cache.entry(charcode).or_insert_with(|| Glyph { a: 3u8 })
}
```

Also, if `Glyph` really is that simple, it should be `Copy` and we can forgo the whole lifetime issue entirely.

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Glyph { a: u8 }
```

Then `find` can return by value.

```
fn find(&self, charcode: GlyphCharCode) -> Option<Glyph> {
  self.cache.get(&charcode).copied()
}
```

No lifetimes needed.

Comment: Thanks Silvio for your help. The Glyph object is a lot more complex than appears here, and creating it requires the use of the freetype library. I will look at your proposal and try doing something with it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Guy I figured it might be minimized for our benefit. In that case, the `entry` approach should work for you. You might also want to use [`or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with) rather than `or_insert` if construction is expensive (I'll edit that into my answer now)

Comment: I've just found it!! Thanks. I will do some tests and mark it as resolved. Thanks a lot!!